# Idiom meaning that trying to attract a certain audience may also attract the wrong audience?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

For example, a nice watch might draw the eye of people you're trying to impress, but it also stands out to thieves. I feel like there's an idiom I had heard expressing this, but I can't remember it for the life of me.

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

The attention was [more than was bargained for](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/more+than+one+bargained+for).

> More than one thought one would get. (Usually in reference to trouble
>   or difficulty.)

-- freedictionary.com

Answer (score 1):

The following phrase is not an idiom but it expresses the idea of attracting the wrong type of "audience" expressed by the OP: [**draw/call attention to**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/call_attention_to) (*cause people to notice*)

> *I've already mentioned that clearly having a smartphone will **draw attention** to yourself, […].  For aggressive robberies, many stories that I've heard on the road involve the person telling it almost always **calling attention to themselves** with nice jewellery, expensive designer clothing, smartphone of course, and any other electronics and such. Keep it out of sight!*

[Source](https://www.fluentin3months.com/theft/): *20 ways to stay safe and prevent theft while travelling*

The following idioms are often reserved for people who visit places notorious for pickpockets and scooter robberies but continue to use their newest iPhones in public and wear the most ostentatious jewellery, such as diamond rings or Rolexes.

Those who flaunt their wealth are either a... 
**[sitting duck](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sitting-duck)**  or a **[sitting target](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sitting-target?a=british)** for thieves.

From the thieves or robbers' point of view, stealing from naïve tourists is like **[shooting fish in a barrel](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+shooting+fish+in+a+barrel)**.

Comment: Drew *unwelcome* attention.

Comment: @Lawrence you can also [draw *unwanted* / *unnecessary* / *undesirable* attention.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=draw+unnecessary+attention%2Cdraw+undesirable+attention%2Cdraw+excessive+attention%2Cdraw+unwelcome+attention&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdraw%20unnecessary%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdraw%20undesirable%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdraw%20excessive%20attention%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdraw%20unwelcome%20attention%3B%2Cc0)